# How to store data from text file to an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, file-io, text-files

I already read data from a text file (in the file there are all numbers (int and double)) and in my class, I have an array of an object type. I have no idea how to put data which read from the txt file into the array.

I would greatly appreciate it if you can give me some answers.

```
 this.object=new Object[nums1];

 File file=new File("/homes/xx.txt");
 try {
      Scanner scnr=new Scanner(file);

      int lineNumber= 1;
      while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
      }
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException  e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

A couple of sample lines from my input file:

```
3
1.0 2.5 3.0
```

I think I need to distinguish between whole numbers and numbers with a decimal point. Should I create another object type so I can store `int` and `double` separately?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should first learn the basics. Read the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: You are reading lines from the file into strings in your program. Would it be OK to store the strings into your array, or do you need to store the individual numbers (ints and doubles)? At least in the latter case you need to show us an example or two of what your lines look like.

Comment: @vanje is right. It sounds like you need to read about arrays once more. You probably have the material in your text book or the like; if not, you may try [the Oracle tutorial on Java arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between integers and non-integers? Or conversely, would it be OK tp read all the numbers as doubles?

Comment: @Ole V.V.    Hi thank you for this link,it looks very helpful and Yes,there files like: 1st line: 3  second line: 1.0 2.5 3.0 I think I need to distinguish them.Should I create another object type hence I can store int and double separately?

Comment: First, when providing more information or explaining the questions further, it’s always best to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47249628/edit) and add the information there. This time I did it for you.

Comment: It depends rather much on what you’ve learned so far and your more precise requirements. You may split each line into individual number strings like [İlker Çetin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249872/5772882) and then detect whether each number contains a decimal point or not. You may declare an array as `Number[]` and store `Integer` and `Double` objects into it, I don’t know if such use of inheritance is too advanced for you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   File file=new File("/homes/xx.txt");
   try {
   Scanner scnr=new Scanner(file);
   List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

  while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
       lines.add(scnr.nextLine());
        System.out.println(lines);
    }

   String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException  e) {
  System.out.println(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space between your integers and doubles, try this:

```
Object []objects = file;
Object []numbers = objects.split(“ “);
```

I am not sure about `Object []objects = file;` part because I am new java learner too. But if you can insert whole text to an array, you can split and assign values one by one with `.split` command to another array.